# Limit direct access to directory using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following folder structure where I have a web app running:

```
/root/public/index.php
```

I have a `.htaccess` in the `/root` that redirects all requests to `/root/public` but I am also able to access my content by prepending the `/public` directory in my request for example at the moment I can do

- `www.example.com/public/index.php`
- `www.example.com/index.php`

Both lead to the same resource but I only want people to access the resource by going to and return an error if they try to directly access the `/public` directory

```
www.example.com/index.php
```

My current `.htaccesss` look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing here to stop the accessibility of my `/public` folder via URLs?

I have tried applying some rewrite rules used by WordPress` but that didn't work for my use-case by following the guide here: https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/htaccess/

Comment: Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the `/public` subdirectory? Do you have other URLs, other than the root/homepage? What about your static assets? You're not actually using WordPress are you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Block direct requests to the "/public" subdirectory
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^public/ - [F]

# Rewrite all requests to "/public/index.php"
RewriteRule ^ public/index.php [END]
```

(The `<IfModule>` wrapper is not required and should be removed.)

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that only direct requests (from the user) are checked and not rewritten requests by the later rewrite.

Note that I changed your existing rule to rewrite the request directly to `/public/index.php` since that would seem to be the intention. (Rather than relying on the `DirectoryIndex`.)

Although, I'm wondering how you are managing your static assets (if any)?